# How to access a yaml file uploaded to a layer in a python aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am using python 3.8 as the lambda runtime for my lambda function which I am trying to deploy using cdk v2. This is a lambda as a custom resource that runs every time the stack deploys.

This is the folder structure

```
 /Dynamics/cust_resource/__init__.py
 /Dynamics/cust_resource/data_objects.py
 /Dynamics/cust_resource/lambda.py
 /Dynamics/cust_resource/requirements.txt
 /Dynamics/deps/config.yaml
 /Dynamics/__init__.py
 /Dynamics/dyna_stack.py
 app.py
```

The lambda function that needs to read off that text config.yaml file. This yaml file is shared by the cdk stack that creates this function. Using S3 is not an option currently. I have packaged the file in a lambda layer. when I download and unzip the layer, I can see that the file exists in the layer I created.

When I try to access the file using either of the options below:

```
with open('config.yaml') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
        print(data)
```

OR

```
with open('deps/config.yaml') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
        print(_data)
```

I get errors as below for the two options:

> Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message
> returned: Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.yaml'

> Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message
> returned: Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'deps/config.yaml'

Comment: did you try `open('Dynamics/deps/config.yaml')`? also I recommend doing `import os

path = os.getcwd()

print(path)` to see where you actually are

Comment: I tried `open('/opt/config.yaml')` That worked following the resolution I saw here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/

Comment: Perfect you can post it as an answer then :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was as below

```
with open('/opt/config.yaml') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
        print(data)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html)

> If your Lambda function includes layers, Lambda extracts the layer
> contents into the /opt directory in the function execution
> environment. Lambda extracts the layers in the order (low to high)
> listed by the function. Lambda merges folders with the same name, so
> if the same file appears in multiple layers, the function uses the
> version in the last extracted layer.